# How to change a column classed as NULL to class integer?

Tags: r, null, dataframe

So I'm starting with a dataframe called max.mins that has 153 rows.

```
    day  Tx      Hx      Tn
1   1   10.0    7.83    2.1
2   2   7.7     6.19    2.5
3   3   7.1     4.86    0.0
4   4   9.8     7.37    2.7
5   5   13.4    12.68   0.4
6   6   17.5    17.47   3.5
7   7   16.5    15.58   6.5
8   8   21.5    20.30   6.2
9   9   21.7    21.41   9.7
10  10  24.4    28.18   8.0
```

I'm applying these statements to the dataframe to look for specific criteria

```
temp_warnings <- subset(max.mins, Tx >= 32 & Tn >=20)
humidex_warnings <- subset(max.mins, Hx >= 40)
```

Now when I open up humidex_warnings for example I have this dataframe

```
   row.names    day    Tx     Hx     Tn
1   41          10    31.1  40.51   20.7
2   56          25    33.4  42.53   19.6
3   72          11    34.1  40.78   18.1
4   73          12    33.8  40.18   18.8
5   74          13    34.1  41.10   22.4
6   79          18    30.3  41.57   22.5
7   94           2    31.4  40.81   20.3
8   96           4    30.7  40.39   20.2
```

The next step is to search for 2 or 3 consective numbers in the column row.names and give me a total of how many times this occurs (I asked this in a previous question and have a function that should work once this problem is sorted out). The issue is that row.names is class NULL which is preventing me from applying further functions to this dataframe.

Help? :)

Thanks in advance,
Nick

Comment: Are you saying that the `row.names` column is class NULL?  As in `class(humidex_warnings[[1]])` returns NULL?

Comment: @Nick Driscoll Are you using `RStudio`? Check the `str(humidex_warnings)`.  The `column` row.names will not be there.

Comment: akrun you're right it's not there and class(humidex_warnings$row.names) = NULL, when I try class(humidex_warnings[[1]]) it gives me "integer"

Comment: @Nick Driscoll That means you don't have to worry about applying the function :-)

Answer (score -1):

If you need the row.names as a data as integer:

humidex_warnings$seq <- as.integer(row.names(humidex_warnings))

If you don't need row.names 
row.names(humidex_warnings) <- NULL

Comment: row.names is not data, is an attribute of the rows.